# What means are there for sending a message to all instances of an application on the same network?

Tags: c#, .net, networking

In my application, I would like to notify all other instances on the same network of certain events in any one instance of the application. What mechanisms or channels do I have to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can [broadcast UDP packets](http://blog.eviac.com/2010/12/network-broadcasting-with-c.html).

```
class Broadcst  
{  
  public static void Main()  
  {  
   Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram,  
                ProtocolType.Udp);  
   IPEndPoint iep1 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 9050);  
   IPEndPoint iep2 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.255"), 9050);  
   string hostname = Dns.GetHostName();  
   byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hostname);  
   sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,SocketOptionName.Broadcast, 1);  
   sock.SendTo(data, iep1);  
   sock.SendTo(data, iep2);  
   sock.Close();  
  }  
}  

class RecvBroadcst  
{  
  public static void Main()  
  {  
   Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,  
           SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);  
   IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);  
   sock.Bind(iep);  
   EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)iep;  
   Console.WriteLine("Ready to receive…");  
   byte[] data = new byte[1024];  
   int recv = sock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref ep);  
   string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);  
   Console.WriteLine("received: {0} from: {1}",stringData, ep.ToString());  
   data = new byte[1024];  
   recv = sock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref ep);  
   stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);  
   Console.WriteLine("received: {0} from: {1}",stringData, ep.ToString());  
   sock.Close();  
  }  
}
```

In order to make it application-specific you can always check if the incoming data follows a defined pattern.